Как правильно перенести файлы из удалённого сервера на локальный, если при выполнении команды scp -r файлы отсутствуют в целевой папке?
Работаю с переносом файлов из удалённого сервера:
[login@alma ~]$ pwd

/home/login

на локальный:
E:\University\Parallel Computing\assignment2.
Находясь локально в директории:
E:\University\Parallel Computing

производя выполнение cmd команды следующего формата:
invzbl3@WIN... /e/University/Parallel Computing
$ scp -r assignment2 login@host:/home/login

я ожидаю получить файлы с удалённого сервера после ввода пароля в локальную директорию.
В результате у меня папка остается пустой.
После этого я перепробовал ещё три команды по типу:

например:


invzbl3@WIN... /e/University/Parallel Computing
$ scp -r login@host:/home/login/assignment2/ assignment2/


sub-папка создаётся, но файлов всё так же там нет.

scp -r login@host:/home/login/assignment2/* assignment2

sub-папка создаётся E:\University\Parallel Computing\assignment2\assignment2, но файлов нет.

scp -r login@host:/home/login/assignment2/* assignment2/

Аналогично с предыдущими двумя. Папка создаётся, но файлы не выгружаются с сервера.
В связи с этим у меня возник вопрос следующего характера:

что я могу упускать в процессе выгрузки файлов из удалённого сервера
на локальный?

Заранее благодарю за любые дельные советы по моему вопросу.
Если будут решения со своей стороны - отпишу.
Если нужна любая дополнительна информация, готов услышать вменяемую обратную связь конструктивную, если она будет.
Заранее благодарю за помощь по моему вопросу.
Для уточнения:
UPD #1:

выгружаю .zip файл.
UPD #2:
Только что разобрался со своим недоразумением, я думал, что смогу выгрузить с помощью cmd команды .zip файл с платформы, как это делал, используя опцию на Github через pull-инг, но, как оказалось, я не смог этого сделать, потому что на удалённом сервере  - alma, у меня нет файлов, мне нужно вручную скачать .zip-файл с образовательной платформы, которую мне предоставили для использования, загрузить его на сервер Alma, а затем только работать над ним с помощью Visual Studio Code.
UPD #3:
проверил отдельно команду в следующем формате:
scp -r assignment2/ login@host:/home/login

адаптировав login & host под себя, и, приняв во внимание совет ниже, изменив название папки вместо "Parallel Computing" на "ParallelComputing", убрав лишний пробел.
Результат тот же:
в папке пусто.


С виндой давно не общаюсь, но меня смущает пробел в имени целевой папки. Попробуй ее переименовать

Вопрос решился следующим образом:

Выгрузил файлы вручную с образовательной платформы на ПК.
Зайдя в директорию существующих файлов через терминал, перенёс имеющиеся файлы с помощью команды:


scp -r assignments login@host:/home/login/

на удалённый сервер.

Работаю напрямую в Visual Studio Code с уже существующими файлами на удалённом сервере.

